# Browser detection does not work consistently in production environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, redirect, web, browser-detection

I am facing a very inconsistent problem at the moment. Basically, I have a browser detection routine in my application, which will sniff user-agent on any incoming request and if it is coming from a supported browser then it will continue loading the application. But if it is not a supported one then it will redirect to "Notsupported.html".

When I wrote this code couple of months ago. it was working great on my machine. I turned it in and it is working great on Dev Server. Great on Test server. no one ever saw n issue with this.

Now, once it is ported to live environment, sometimes it loads browsernotsupported page when user loads it for the first time and user's machine has been idle for a while. Sometimes it does not to be sitting idle for a while. It just happens randomly but ocurances are noticed more often after machine has been sitting idle for a while or machine just restarted. But it is not guaranteed that it will happen for sure.

I am pretty sure that Production has many settings that are different than other environments but I have no idea why it would fail to detect the browser in production machine and not anywhere else. I am trying to reproduce issues but it is completely not repeatable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

User-agents aren't a very reliable way to determine what browser the client is using, as they can be modified by the user. The better approach is to specifically detect if the browser supports features that your app needs with a service like [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/).

Comment: Well, granted the fact that user agents are not the most reliable way to do it and users can change the browser. We are the users at the moment. Our team is testing it a the moment and we are seeing the issue. One major difference is that production environment is behind a lad balancer while others are not. I am yet to establish a causal relationship between load balancer and browser detection failure.

Answer (score 0):

> It just happens randomly

The good thing about computers is that they never do anything randomly :)

You are giving very little information on how you are detecting the browser. What code are you using? Which browsers do you support? What user-agents are being falsely redirected?

Also keep in mind that many applications change the user agent, for example advertising the .NET version present on the machine. This may lead to false matches.

Comment: `HttpRequest.Browser.Majorversion` is what I am using for the browser detection and that is of course server side.`What user-agents are being falsely redirected?` As I said, it is truly random behavior sometimes Chrome, sometimes IE,Mozilla, safari. I don't this that the problem is with client side or any particular user-agents have problem I think it is related to something on the server and on a condition which we are not able to identify yet.

Comment: I meant the full user-agent string, not just which browser. It may give a clue why it's falsely detecting the browser in some (at the moment seemingly random) cases.

Comment: what do you mean by ` user-agent string`?

Comment: What the browser sends in the request. Like displayed at http://www.useragentstring.com/

Comment: Oh ok. The only trace of user-agent string we have at this moment is IIS logs and we don't know which one of these forwarded to browsernot supported and which ones were processed normally. Until and unless we install visual studio on a production machine and run the project and trace it at run time when it fails, we can say this is how user-agent string looks like when it failed.

Answer (score 0):

In IE it can be linked with compatibility mode. If ie in competibility mode, it sends very strange information about self